# Understanding jQuery's .eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's `.eq()` is:

```
eq: function( i ) {
    return i === -1 ?
        this.slice( i ) :
        this.slice( i, +i + 1 );
},
```

What is the point of the first `+` in `+i + 1`?

Comment: Note that the whole reason why the `i === -1` check is done is because `eq(-1)` is the only case where it cannot be substituted by `slice`. For instance `eq(2)` is `slice(2,3)`, `eq(-2)` is `slice(-2,-1)`, but `eq(-1)` cannot become `slice(-1,0)` since that one doesn't work...

Comment: It would be nice if `.slice` did differ between `-0` and `0` (which *are* distinct values in JavaScript).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to cast the value to integer and to ensure that you are performing an integer addition instead of string concatenation.

Compare those two for example:

```
var i = '1';
var result = i + 1; // result = '11';
var result2 = +i + 1; // result = 2;
```

And to answer the question why this is not used as the first argument of the slice method, it is because the slice method internally performs the conversion. So for example the following will work as expected:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var result = array.slice('1', '2'); // result = [2];
```

Comment: But then why not do it for the other instance of i?

Comment: @Randomblue, most probably because the `slice` method already does this cast.

Comment: Hum. What if someone did `eq('-1')`? Then `i === -1` would be false so the last part of the ternary statement would be called, which is incorrect.

Comment: @pimvdb It's not a bug since the `eq` method is defined to only take integer Number values, not strings...

Comment: (although tbh, the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq) clearly state an integer is the expected parameter type, so if I was writing that function, I wouldn't bother with the `+i` in the first place...)

Comment: @Randomblue, yeap, seems like a bug.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: It's defined to accept an integer, not necessarily a number. You could interpret it as being defined such that it accepts a string representing an integer :)

Comment: @pimvdb Luckily, jQuery does define what the term "integer" means: http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Integer `:)`

Answer (score 2):

The unary `+` operator coerces the operand to the Number type. The idea is to fix String values like `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, etc.

Comment: Why isn't the `+` used everywhere, then?

Comment: @Randomblue: Because `+i + 1` is the only expression which performs a mathematical operation.

Comment: @Randomblue You don't need it in the `===` operation since that operation already checks the type (in this case, the left operand has to be of type Number, since the right operand is of that type).

Comment: Aha. It seems then that the case `.eq('-1')` is not fixed.

Comment: @Randomblue Yes, `.eq('-2')` and `.eq('-0')` work, but `.eq('-1')` doesn't.

Comment: @Robusto: Sounds good. Maybe there would be a small performance cost.

Comment: @Robusto: Also take into account file size is of great importance. `+i` is one character, whereas `parseInt(i,10)` is 14 characters.

Comment: @Randomblue `+1 === -1` fixes the "issue", no need for `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sure `i` gets treated as a number and not as a string.

If `3` gets treated as a string, `3 + 1` would be `31`.